# Пример парсинга и вырезания строки, приведите пожалуйста

Tags: javascript

На js надо реализовать парсер открывающего и закрывающего тега, а точнее текста внутри этих тегов, допустим вот наш текст

```
"Привет дорогой друг, давно тебе не писал. <&&*>text<*&&> <&&*>text<*&&>"
```

надо рекурсивно продолжать парсинг (не предлагайте   библиотеки  bb кодов), нужно решение в пару строк.

Comment: [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Comment: Или на худой конец использовать регулярки, например: ```"Привет дорогой друг, давно тебе не писал. <&&*>text<*&&> <&&*>text<*&&>".replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '')```

Comment: без регулярки можете пример привести?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот несколько примеров решения задачи:

```
  var txt = "Привет дорогой друг, давно тебе не писал. <a href=''>text</a> <span>text</span>";
  // используя jQuery
  document.write($('<p>' + txt + '</p>').text());
  // используя создание элемента (может привести к XSS)
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = txt;
  document.write(div.innerContent || div.innerText || '');
  // используя регулярные выражения
  document.write(txt.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, ''));
  // используя split (по сути дублирует решение с регулярками)
  document.write(txt.split(/<[^>]*>/g).join(''));
  // используя DOMParser
  var doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(txt, "text/html");
  document.write(doc.body.innerText);
```

Существуют и другие варианты решения, причем у каждого из них будут как свои достоинства, так и недостатки.